# What is the syntax for Typescript arrow functions with generics?

Tags: typescript

The typescript handbook currently has nothing on arrow functions. Normal functions
can be generically typed with this syntax:
example:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

What is the syntax for arrow functions?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The language specification says on p.64f

> A construct of the form < T > ( ... ) => { ... } could be parsed as an
>   arrow function expression with a type parameter or a type assertion
>   applied to an arrow function with no type parameter. It is resolved as
>   the former[..]

example:

```
// helper function needed because Backbone-couchdb's sync does not return a jqxhr
let fetched = <
           R extends Backbone.Collection<any> >(c:R) => {
               return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
                   c.fetch({reset: true, success: fulfill, error: reject})
               });
           };
```

Answer (score 1039):

## Edit

Per @Thomas comment, in newer TS compilers, we can simply do:

```
const foo = <T,>(x: T) => x;
```

## Original Answer

The full example explaining the syntax [referenced by Robin](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/generics#design-pattern-convenience-generic)... brought it home for me:

### Generic functions

Something like the following works fine:

```
function foo<T>(x: T): T { return x; }
```

However using an arrow generic function will not:

```
const foo = <T>(x: T) => x; // ERROR : unclosed `T` tag
```

Workaround: Use extends on the generic parameter to hint the compiler
that it's a generic, e.g.:

```
const foo = <T extends unknown>(x: T) => x;
```

Comment: would it be possible to declare some predefined generic type for `const foo`? i.e. `type GenericFun<T, A=T> = (payload: A) => T;` then make `const foo: GenericFun` still generic without providing a `T` type?

Comment: @ciekawy, AFAIK, it's not, and I think that makes sense. Generics are about allowing higher order types in a sense. `GenericFun<T, A=T>` defines a set that includes _other types_ `GenericFun<number>` and `GenericFun<string>`, among others. Allowing generic types to constitute a type annotation directly - e.g. const `const foo: GenericFun` - however, would tend to erode the static safety otherwise provided by requiring specificity e.g `const foo: GenericFun<string>` or `const foo: GenericFun<number>`

Comment: Your second example is only an error in a `.tsx` file (TypeScript + JSX). In a `.ts` file it works fine, as you can see on the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20foo%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(x%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20x%3B%0D%0A).

Comment: Newer typescript compilers also support trailing comma `const foo = <T,>(x: T) => x;` to sidestep the JSX ambiguity.

Comment: @danvk Worth noting this only holds true for those who have forbidden JSX in TS files - if a project is configured to allow JSX in TS files you'll still need the "extends" or the trailing comma

Comment: So is this the takeaway: "use .ts instead of .tsx extensions"?

Comment: certainly don't use .tsx if you don't intend to use any JSX.  For me it helps to distinguish files which have some components vs files with some sort of functionality...

Comment: Dear TS team, Would be nice to do this without using hacks. Arrow functions are quite common these days.

Comment: how to set default generic type? `const foo = <T = any,>(x: T) => x` not work, i always get `unknown`

Comment: Worth mentioning if you have the Prettier setup and it removes the trailing comma, the trailing comma workaround won't work.

Comment: To set the default generic type, I had to `const foo = <T extends unknown = {}>(x: T) => x`. Still annoying in 2021

Comment: Based on the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types), you can create a generic arrow function like so: `const foo: <T>(x: T) => T = (x) => x`

Comment: @ciekawy I have trouble understanding the difference between `type GenericFun1<T> = () => T` and `type GenericFun2 = <T>() => T` ... ts seem to handle them differently as doing `type GenericFun3 = GenericFun2<number>` will raise an error. Any hints ?

Answer (score 340):

If you're in a `.tsx` file you cannot just write `<T>`, but this works:

```
const foo = <T, >(x: T) => x;
```

As opposed to the `extends {}` hack, this hack at least preserves the intent.

Comment: Do they plan to fix this behavior?

Comment: I guess there is not much that could be done about this... the JSX and Typescript generic syntaxes just clash here..

Comment: What about default type parameter type? `const foo = <T = any,>(x: T) => x` doesn't work...

Comment: Why does this hack work? what is the comma saying in this case?

Comment: @w4tson if you had two generics, you could write `<T, F>`... apparently you can omit the second..

Comment: @MikhailVasin Unfortunately does not work, had to use `extends`, did you find more elegant solution?

Comment: @MikhailVasin but separating types and implementation works: `const foo: <T = any,>(x: T) => T = (v) => v`

Comment: @w4tson, wild guess - the compiler can distinguish it from JSX since <T, > isn't valid JSX but is valid TS or TSX.

Answer (score 111):

I found the example above confusing.
I am using React and JSX so I think it complicated the scenario.

I got clarification from [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/generics.html), which states for arrow generics:

Workaround: Use extends on the generic parameter to hint the compiler that it's a generic, this came from a simpler example that helped me.

```
    const identity = < T extends {} >(arg: T): T => { return arg; }
```

Comment: While it works nicely, I must say that it does look like a bit of a hack...

Answer (score 61):

This works for me

```
const Generic = <T> (value: T) => {
    return value;
}
```

Comment: If In `.ts` file this works. Otherwise one has to extend.

Comment: Works perfectly fine:
https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/DYUwLgBAzgFg9gVzIsAVAngBxBAvBAHlQD4AKANwENgEQAuCVASj2ImpACcxSADKmjjBYcASygQAJAG9h2OADMIA2gF9eTANwAobbBQoM2UgCJKlE0yA

Comment: this is working fine for me in .ts and .tsx files in vscode

Comment: JSX element 'T' has no corresponding closing tag.ts(17008)
Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304) does NOT work in tsx files for me in vs code

Answer (score 26):

so late, but with ES6 no need extends it still work for me.... :)

```
let getArray = <T>(items: T[]): T[] => {
    return new Array<T>().concat(items)
}

let myNumArr = getArray<number>([100, 200, 300]);
let myStrArr = getArray<string>(["Hello", "World"]);
myNumArr.push(1)
console.log(myNumArr)
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I have to add a comma like so: `<T, >`. as described in @Thomas comment under @jbmilgrom' answer

Comment: You should read the other solutions before posting one. Your solution has already been posted with explanation.  It works only inside of a .ts file, not a .tsx file.

Comment: doesn work, as doesn't a comma. Syntax error caught by VSCode

Answer (score 22):

This works for me

```
 const logSomething = <T>(something:T): T => {
       return something;
    }
```

Comment: But this was already suggested many times

Answer (score 12):

while the popular answer with `extends {}` works and is better than `extends any`, it forces the `T` to be an object

```
const foo = <T extends {}>(x: T) => x;
```

to avoid this and preserve the type-safety, you can use `extends unknown` instead

```
const foo = <T extends unknown>(x: T) => x;
```

Answer (score 11):

I use this type of declaration:

```js
const identity: { <T>(arg: T): T } = (arg) => arg;
```

It allows defining additional props to your function if you ever need to, and in some cases, it helps keep the function body cleaner from the generic definition.

If you don't need the additional props (namespace sort of thing), it can be simplified to:

```js
const identity: <T>(arg: T) => T = (arg) => arg;
```

Comment: When using `<T>` inside the function body, this did not work for me. Typescript tells me `<T>` isn't used for the `<T>` at the function definition location and tells me that it cannot find `<T>` at the position where I refer to it in the function body. 

With the `<T,>` 'hack' I do not have this issue.

Answer (score 10):

The non-arrow function way.  Expanding on the example from the OP.

```
function foo<T>(abc: T): T {
    console.log(abc);
    return abc;
}

const x = { abc: 123 };
foo(x);

const y = 123;
foo<number>(y);
```

Aside from the answer of embedding the whole thing into one statement:

```
const yar = <T,>(abc: T) => {
    console.log(abc);
    return abc;
}
```

Another approach is to have an intermediate type:

```
type XX = <T>(abc: T) => T;

const bar: XX = (abc) => {
    console.log(abc);
    return abc;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACgIYBGEAXIhgJSkaIDeAUIo4hAgM5wA2ApgHQdwBzfEXIBuBkwBOXKCElJCEcQF86UAJ4AHLogAauxAF5EmXIqrkjWMuLoswrKIgJ5JpfUcTCIlw9fpMzGycvPxCimISjNKy8oiKKnR2bE7qrp6YADRmRBZWtFFBDiF8gt6RgTFyCkSJyQ5OAB6eNPG5iACMAEwAzIjK4ihwOI2RLpIjkWkTo7b2jojqnt09g6hoYCAAtgRckrjqY64b27v7OIfi0yc7eweRQA)

Answer (score 5):

I know I am late to this answer. But thought of answering this in case anyone else finds it helpful. None of the answers mention how to use generics with an  `async` arrow function.

Here it goes :

```
const example = async <T> (value: T) => {
    //awaiting for some Promise to resolve or reject;
     const result = await randomApi.getData(value);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2021, Ts 4.3.3

```
const useRequest = <DataType, ErrorType>(url: string): Response<DataType, ErrorType> 
   => {
      ...
   }
```

Comment: move => 1 line above if u want

Answer (score 2):

Adding an example for multiple depended generic types:

This function, was converted to arrow function as the following:

```
http.get = function <T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R> {
            config.withCredentials = true;
            ....
          };
```

Notice the extends instead of the equal sign:

```
http.get = async <T extends any, R extends unknown = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R> => {
            config.withCredentials = true;
            ...
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const identity = <T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

Comment: The advantage of the comma in the other answer is because this will break if you have TSX (React) code.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Using <T, extends {}> throws an error when you try to pass null as parameter. I will prefer using <T,> because it clears the issue. I am yet to get the reason why. But this worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Here I got 2 cases of arrow function with generics:

- To call directly:

```
const foo = <T>(value: T): void => {
    console.log(value);
foo('hello') // hello
}
```

- To create a type to use later:

```
type TFoo<S> = (value: S) => boolean;
const foo: TFoo<number> = (value) => value>0;
console.log(foo(1)) // true
console.log(foo(-1)) // false
```

Hopefully this helps somewhere!

Answer (score -3):

If need make return method generic, it didn't show errors with extra data
ex:

```
export type DataGenerator<T> = (props: {name: string}) => T;

const dataGenerator: DataGenerator<{city?: string}> = ({  name }) => {
    return {
        city: `${name}`,
        name: "aaa",
    }
}

dataGenerator({name: "xxx"})
```

I need to show error on `name`