# How to convert function to arrow function in TS

Tags: typescript

I have the following function in TS, I would like to rewrite it to an arrow function.

I tried with no result. Could you please point me the right direction?
Thanks!

```
function log<T>(message: T): IO<void> {
  return new IO(() => console.log(message));
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention the problem you are facing?

Comment: @ParthS007 I would like to rewrite that function as arrow function...

Comment: I am trying smt like... with no success:

const log = (message: T): IO<void> => new IO(() => console.log(message));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the syntax for Typescript arrow functions with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics)

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt was close, but you  forgot to include the generic argument declaration in front of the arrow function parameters. Try something like this:

```
const log = <T>(message: T): IO<void> =>
   new IO(() => console.log(message));
```

If you're working in a .tsx file, [you may need to do something a little more complex to make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112882/3124288).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use:

```
const log = <T>(message: T): IO<void> => new IO(() => console.log(message));
```