# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IResponseConfig'

Tags: javascript, typescript

So running into another vague Typescript error.

I have the following function `fetchAllAssets` which ends with dispatching an action and running the `responses` through a function called `formatAssets`.

And the error is on the `responses` array.

```
export const fetchAllAssets = () => (dispatch: DispatchAllAssets) => {
  dispatch(actionGetAllAssets());
  return fetchAll([getPrices(), getAvailableSupply()]).then((responses) =>
    dispatch(actionSetAllAssets(formatAssets(responses))));
}
```

The **formatAssets** function:

```
export const formatAssets = (responses: IResponseConfig[]) => {
  let prices: any;
  let availableSupplies: any;
  console.log('responses', responses);
  responses.forEach((response: IResponseConfig) => {
    const { config } = response;
    const { url } = config;
    if (url.includes('prices')) {
      prices = response.data;
    } else if (url.includes('dashboard')) {
      availableSupplies = cleanAssets(response.data);
    }
    return {
      prices,
      availableSupplies
    };
  });
```

**The Error**

[image]

> Argument of type '[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IResponseConfig[]'.
>     Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IResponseConfig': config, data ts(2345)

Here is what the interface for **IResponseConfig** looks like:

```
export interface IResponseConfig {
  config: {
    adapter: any;
    baseUrl: string;
    headers: {};
    maxContentLength: number;
    method: string;
    params: {
      key: string;
    }
    timeout: number;
    transformRequest: {};
    transformResponse: {};
    url: string;
    validateStatus: any;
    xsrfCookieName: string;
    xsrfHeaderName: string;
  };
  data: IAssetResponse[];
  headers?: {};
  request?: XMLHttpRequest;
  upload?: XMLHttpRequestUpload;
  status?: number;
  statusText?: string;
}
```

And here is what responses is:

[image]

What shape should **IResponseConfig** take in order for the error to go away?

### Signature of fetchAll

```
// @TODO Fix any type.
export const fetchAll = (array: any) => Promise.all(array);
```

### Also I was able to remove the error by making all keys optional (hack?)

```
export interface IResponseConfig {
  config?: any;
  data?: IAssetResponse[];
  headers?: any;
  request?: XMLHttpRequest;
  upload?: XMLHttpRequestUpload;
  status?: number;
  statusText?: string;
}
```

What `IAssetResponse` looks like (the actual data I care about)

```
export interface IAssetResponse {
  [key: string]: string | undefined;
  currency: string;
  price?: string;
  availableSupply?: string;
  maxSupply?: string;
}
```

Comment: It seems like it's actually an issue with `fetchAll`. What's its signature?

Comment: @p.s.w.g added it! Also found out if I added `?` to all the keys the error goes away, but I feel that is a hack?

Comment: You probably don't want all parameters to be optional, that is most likely a non-deal hack/workaround for the actual issue here.  I agree, something is probably not right with `fetchAll`.  You have something returning an array of untyped objects, so that's all it can guess at here.  You need to add typedefs everywhere you can to avoid issues like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to define `fetchAll` as a generic function, like this:

```
export const fetchAll = <T extends {}>(array: (T | Promise<T>)[]) => Promise.all(array);
```

<sup>NOTE: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32308370/1715579) for a discussion on why `<T>(array T[]) => ...` fails to parse as you might expect.</sup>

Assuming, that `getPrices` and `getAvailableSupply` both return either a `IResponseConfig` or `Promise<IResponseConfig>`, the parameter `responses` will be inferred to be of type `IResponseConfig[]`.

If this is not the case, you may have to add some additional conversions, type hints, or assertions to coerce them into a consistent interface.

Comment: Hmm thanks, trying to wrap my head about the `<T>` currently getting `Argument of type 'Promise<any>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IResponseConfig[]'.
  Type 'Promise<any>' has no properties in common with type 'IResponseConfig'` wondering if for the sake of another dev understanding context, `any` would suffice, since the arrays are strongly typed elsewhere.

Comment: @LeonGaban Ahh, I should have accounted for `Promise<T>` in the parameter type hint. See my updated answer. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Sweet Yes that worked! :D I don't need to rely on `any` anymore. And great link which linked to generics: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/generics.html