# Significance of "extends {}"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In existing code, I've come across type parameter declarations like this: `<Param extends {}>`.

My question is, what is the meaning of the `extends {}` part? How does it differ from simply `<Param>`?

---

Example:

```js
type Fold<S extends {}, D extends {}> = {
  folder: ...
}
```

Comment: Difficult to say without the code, maybe to prevent primitive type such as string, number, undefined... Do you have an example?

Comment: @HTN: That does not exclude primitives, `object` would do that.

Comment: @HTN [it doesn't prevent primitives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgHgCqIKYA8rZgoDOiA3gL4B8AFLgFyIYCUjWZAsAFACQATtigg+SXAG5uFbtK4AbQYjAgAtoyXKARtj6IAvMhQ0ArMwlyFxKH0aW+MMAHM9BmgCIAFtlmy4r093koRDgNACtGENDsaGdUGjJEYDg4RlcNAEM+V0QKUyA). I don't actually know what it does, though. It's a lower bound for absolutely anything. Might prevent `never`, not sure.

Comment: [doesn't filter out `never`, either](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgHgCqIKYA8rZgoDOiA3gL4B8AFLgFyIYCUjWZAsAFACQATtigg+SXAG5uFbtK4AbQYjAgAtoyXKARtj6IAvMhQ0ArMwlyFxKH0aW+MMAHM9BmgCIAFtlmy4r093koRDgNACtGENDsaGdUGjJEYDg4RlcNAEM+V0QKfy5uFGjZTOxEQMVsADc1Ku0zcrA4AAdS-TiwKuYgA). I'm curious for this usage, as well. Might just be an artefact of *something* being there before but later removed. Or a pattern so you can quickly fill in a property in the future.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @ford04 Added an example, is that sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `{}` vs `unknown` constraint

If you write `<S>`, `S` is [unconstrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) - it [behaves like](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown) `<S extends unknown>` (TS 3.5+).

`{}` type can take every value (incl. primitives), except `null` or `undefined` with [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

`unknown` is more or less `{} | null | undefined`, making `{}` a more narrow subtype:

```
type FoldImplicit<S> = S
type FoldObject<S extends {}> = S

type T1 = FoldImplicit<"foo"> // ✅ 
type T2 = FoldImplicit<undefined> // ✅
type T3 = FoldObject<"foo"> // ✅
type T4 = FoldObject<undefined> // ❌ - `undefined` not in `{}` (strictNullChecks)
// compiles with `strictNullChecks` disabled 
// - null and undefined now belong to every type.
```

---

### Where do I see these constructs?

The most often encountered case is probably with [React generic components](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/advanced/guides/generic_components):

```
// help compiler to distinguish JSX tag from generic component declaration
const Comp = <T extends {}>(props: { foo: T }) => <div>...</div>
```

To match [implicit constraints](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown) more closely, you can write `<T extends unknown>` or just [`<T,>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics) (note the comma). Before TS 3.5, the implicit constraint has been `{}`.

With `extends {}`, you can also take away `undefined` or `null` as possible inputs. But in my opinion a) it makes code unnecessarily verbose b) you better find a more narrow constraint for stronger types.

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChSYBPMJOAMQgBsATASXEeDWBgB4BlAHxwAvHH4VqtBiwDyAIwBWSDALhIAHjCQA7ZgGc4AbwC+wsRMk04AFQCMo+kzYcuPXvkwQI+YQHo-OEBQcjgAOQhtAC44AANTGLgURn0IODQUHTgYFABrWjAoUB5gADckfStaGwAmRxkXME5uPgBXPSRMYB0kZn9AoMrbAGY65wVlVU9vXzgA4MGbABZRuSUVVvbO7t7ZwMAZcjgAWli25g6unoSdCLgu2Pi4AAp9GEKMUJbGRgBhAAsVHL6ACU5DQEB0Lzg31wYEcvBs6i0ugMxjMjwKEDA+miRjgXgg0QRJiBomEvGYpUEAAkkF9UkYAFL8WShAB0L0KOgA5sBMJR0Tgsaz8UCTLw-BSSoJSGCIfBoeBamJ4XAADSCAWY7HGPHeQlwYmkuDkyk0unGJks9mvLo8vmaoUisUSymkOayyEKsAjZU2DUYrE4-H6w0iMmS6m0xj0y1sjm23n8gP6YXeUXiiO7dRQHBQCrkIA)