# How to access generic TypeScript type in function body?

Tags: typescript, function, generics

Using a generic type on a TypeScript function:

```js
const func: <T extends number>() => void = () => {
   const x: T = 1
}
```

Emits the following error:

```
Cannot find name 'T'.  TS2304

    69 | const func: <T extends number>() => void = () => {
  > 70 |    const x: T = 1
       |             ^
    71 | }
```

How can I use generic types inside a function (and not just on its signature)?

Comment: The syntax is `const func = <T extends number>() => { const x: T = 1 }`. You'll get another error, but this is already another question 

Answer (score 2):

If you want to type arrow functions, try using the implied typing method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576880/7355232).

```js
const func = <T extends number>(x: T) => x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the alternative function notation makes that error disappear:

```js
function func<T extends number>(): void {
   const x: T = 1
}
```

And we instead get the following error, which makes sense:

```
Type '1' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '1' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'number'.  TS2322

    69 | export function func<T extends number>(): void {
  > 70 |    const x: T = 1
       |          ^
    71 | }
```