# typescript - pass a type to a function parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm still new to typescript, but I'm trying to pass a custom type to a function. I'm avoiding using "any" for this case, here is my example.

```js
interface ReturnObj<T> {
  returnObj: T | null
}

const createResultObj = (
    isSuccessful: boolean = false,
    returnObj: ReturnObj = null,
    errors: AppError | null = null,
    statusCode: number = 500
   ): Result => {
return {
       isSuccessful,
       returnObj,
       errors,
       statusCode
     }
}
```

Naturally, this is returning an error with `Generic type 'ReturnObj<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).` but I'm not sure how to fill this part in so that I can call in this function and include the type if something exists in the returnObj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to is give a generic parameter to your function like below:

```
interface ReturnObj<T> {
  returnObj: T | null
}

type AppError = {} | null
type Result<T extends unknown> = {
  isSuccessful: boolean,
  returnObj: ReturnObj<T> | null,
  errors: AppError,
  statusCode: number
}

const createResultObj = <T extends unknown>(
  isSuccessful: boolean = false,
  returnObj: ReturnObj<T> | null = null,
  errors: AppError = null,
  statusCode: number = 500
): Result<T> => {
  return {
    isSuccessful,
    returnObj,
    errors,
    statusCode
  }
}

type sth = { foo: string };
const s: sth = { foo: "bar" }
const returnS: ReturnObj<sth> = { returnObj: s }
const re = createResultObj(true, returnS, null, 200);
console.log(re);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoTAVyiA8gIwCsAeAFQD5kBvAKGWSg2zyIC5lTkAfZETAG340AvjRpgAngAcUAQSlSAolCgB7KMgC81Yd14ChkmWggBnAWDLIIAD0ggAJqeSYQAaxCqA7iErba9MCmAMqYCEimpjAC7PiqqvwQcCAANHQMTDgEhOzoWFlEZJQ8fIJp9NBqUKbs8koq6uXIpmBwWKYAwqoOEOx8ALb40CJiCKogLcgIjG0Q6Ob8YNlayFa29k4u7p4+5AAU6UGh4WZRMchxCUkgK-D8phBNjPksOSYv2UV6pfwrP02VdQ1ZB1ZRVP4GJotNqYTrdXr6QbQFYAVgADGiaABKXJmCxfTSUAIZF7UdKBEJhCJnfhNejPZjZOnWBrVZnQ9pdHrpUSicTSFAtAAWKyoyBg8XYLSgoAA5shhABuGhjCZgZpSsAi-ziyXIABE+DgUH1CpV40mDJwwVxH0Kwr81BJjLYzTNqstKG00ySkHmFmyezAUEwj2d1pS+jKyAATBiscqPVcAHT8VSyvaMBNAA)

Note: `<T extends unknown>` is an obligation because of arrow function usage see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576880/12354911)

Comment: ahhh that makes perfect sense, thank you. I wasn't sure how to define the Result type with the generic so this works out perfectly. Appreciate the explanation and resource.