# Why does this syntax works vs arrow function syntax for the component im trying to create?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm following a short tutorial on youtube, a question I have is, why does this syntax work when creating my component:

```
function List<ListItem>({
  items,
  render,
}: {
  items: ListItem[];
  render: (item: ListItem) => ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{render(item)}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

I prefer arrow functions, I've tried writing it out like this:

```
const List<ListItem> = ({
  items, 
  render
}: {
  items: ListItem[],
  render: (item: ListItem) => ReactNode
}) => {
  return (
  <ul>
    {items.map((item, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        {render(item)}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
  )
}
```

I'm getting this message in vs code :

> JSX element 'ListItem' has no corresponding closing tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the syntax for Typescript arrow functions with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you.  I did not know the name of that item was a "generic".