# How can I dynamically set the type of state inside a custom hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am building a custom hook and I want to set the state type the same as the initial state type

```
const useCustomHook = (initialState)=>{
     ...
  const [state,setState] = useState<someDynamicType>(initialState);
     ...
}
```

How can I do this?
Initial state could be anything and not always the same type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass `someDynamicType` as a type parameter to the function. It's a bit more convenient if you use an anonymous function instead of a lambda:

```
const useCustomHook = function<T>(initialState: T) {
     ...
  const [state,setState] = useState<T>(initialState);
     ...
}
```

You could also use a lambda, but the syntax is a bit more clunky: ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics))

```
const useCustomHook = <T extends unknown>(initialState: T) => {
     ...
  const [state,setState] = useState<T>(initialState);
     ...
}
```

Comment: This answer is better because it also explains a solution to the issue of "<" and ">" when enabling TSX support.

Answer (score 0):

Use generics to add a type to the `initialState`, and the `useState` hook:

```
const useCustomHook = <T>(initialState: T)=>{
     ...
  const [state,setState] = useState<T>(initialState);
     ...
}
```

When using the custom hook, the state would get the type of the initial state. For example:

```
const x = null

useCustomHook(x)
```

In this case the state type would be `null`. In cases like that you can explicitly set the type:

```
type X = { a: boolean, b: string }

useCustomHook<X | null>(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic type as documented here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

```
const useCustomHook = <T>(initialState:T) => {
  const [state,setState] = useState<T>(initialState);
  // state is now `T`
}
```