# return response.value as generic in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, microsoft-graph-api, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I have an agent.ts typescript file that will be responsible for api calls.

```
const responseBody = (response: any) => response.value;

const requests = {
    get: (url: string) => getGraphClient().api(url).get().then(responseBody)
}

const Activities = {
    list: () => requests.get(academicCalendarURL)
}

const agent = {
    Activities,
}

export default agent;
```

this works fine however I would like to use generics.  but I am receiving an error

```
interface ResponseBody{
    body: any;
  }

const responseBody = <T extends ResponseBody>(response: T): any => response.body;

const requests = {
    get: <T>(url: string) => getGraphClient().api(url).get().then(responseBody) //error 1
}

const Activities = {
    list: () => requests.get<Activity[]>(academicCalendarURL)
}

const agent = {
    Activities
}

export default agent;
```

error 1

```
  'T' is declared but its value is never read
```

Answer (score 1):

You should extend generic type with new interface. Also can use `<T,>` for generic arrow funtion. see: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics)

```
interface ResponseBody{
  body: any;
}
const responseBody = <T extends ResponseBody>(response: Type): any => response.body;

const requests = {
        get: <T,>(url: string) => /// 
    }
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4AcD2IMQBCOAJgJ4DeAUMsgEalkBcycIZA3FQL5UJ4YwyKJlz4ijZAF5kAHgAqyCAA9IIEhjSiBE8gD4AFCOw6W8gJQs2ZaXuHbxAOgbkufAUJEBHAK6YwmrQyyNS0YWEA5hBgLAoANHYGPlAANiyCUKAR5rYh-Pg4KRCOKTgRBgBEcBgkFea84dzIVKCQsIgoAIIIYMAAbsBglDTIwCRMID4AtnTQXA35gsjdvQO9mNIhI7QpwIIsBjlSdt5+ghiOUWCyK-2DZADaALqGVQhwJBBTwAgAwnBFdRwKAAVVQABk6jwqO58EI4FFwJtQrRbmtgJg4tDwkA)

Comment: thanks how do I pass my type to this?  `list: () => requests.get<Activity[]>(academicCalendarURL)`  `expected 0 type arguments but got 1`

Comment: thank you I am down to one error (I edited my question)  I am receiving `'T' is declared but its value is never read`   on the get function. not sure where to place the T in the get function.

Comment: I think you shouldn't edit because question and answer will be misleading as well as cannot help for people who will experience similar problems. For your last problem, you can look this [link](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-is-declared-but-its-value-is-never-read#:~:text=To%20solve%20%27is%20declared%20but,error%20in%20your%20entire%20project.)

Comment: thanks that link addresses ignoring unused variables, but I would like to use the variable, I want to pass the type into the get function.  anyway I will leave the question open for a bit, thanks for your help.