# TypeScript Generic type for generated function

Tags: typescript

How do I declare generic type for a function created dynamically?

```
type FooType = {
  username: string;
}

type BarType = {
  age: number;
}

interface DataStore {
  foo: FooType;
  bar: BarType;
}

const getDataStore = () => ({
  foo: { username: 'Tera' },
  bar: { age: 24 },
})

const generateFunction = <T, S extends keyof DataStore>(slice: S) => {
  type DataSlice = DataStore[S];

  return (selector: (store: DataSlice) => T) => selector(getDataStore()?.[slice]);
}
```

How do I use `T` in `useFoo` and pass `generateFunction`?

```
const useFoo = generateFunction('foo');
```

Expected usage of `useFoo`

```
type UserName = string;

const userName = useFoo<UserName>((foo: FooType) => foo.userName);
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example. User, getDataStore, FooType,BarType are not defined

Comment: Are you looking for `generateFunction<T>('foo');` where `T` is your desired return type for  the generated function?

Comment: @MichaelBrenndoerfer yes, but how do I declare `T` for `useFoo` in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for generic anonymous functions (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576880/885098)).

```js
const generateFunction = <S extends keyof DataStore>(slice: S) => {
  type DataSlice = DataStore[S];

  return <T,>(selector: (store: DataSlice) => T) => selector(getDataStore()?.[slice]);
}
```

Note that the `T` generic is now associated with the returned function, instead of `generateFunction` itself. As written in your question, `generateFunction` is a generic function that takes two generic parameters `T` and `S` that are *known when calling the function*. Instead, you want `generateFunction` to take a single generic parameter `S` that's known when calling, and have it return a function with a single generic parameter `T` that's only known when *the returned function is called*.