# how to explicitly assert the type of a generic function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say I have the type of a generic function defined somewhere:

```
type FArA = <T>(t: T)=>T // function taking type T and returning type T
```

I then define a function of that type:

```
function f<T>(a: T):T {return a;}
```

I know of no syntax to succinctly declare (and have the compiler typecheck) that `f` is indeed of type `FArA`. The only workarounds I can think of are to use an otherwise needless assignment:

```
const g: FArA = f;
```

… or to take the function expression approach (as advised in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576880/274677)) whose syntax, however I find odd:

```
const f2: FArA = <T,>(a: T):T=>a
```

Is there another way?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgggJzlAvFAPAFQHwApgBcUmAlCtpgFCUBmArgHYDGwAlgPYNQ1Z4CGRUgUxQA3ggjA6CLnwDcAX2pNOAZ2DcATEXhJUGTABp%20gksPJ9lajQHMdiZGhpzqAG0lQARvpq4AzCQulEA)

Comment: Is it only odd because of `<T,>`? The extra comma is there so it isn't confused with a JSX tag.

Comment: There is no other way, but in 4.9 we have `satisfies`, which will look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkKQ9W). Frankly, this isn't a big problem to most users. Is this just something that is inconvenient?

Comment: @caTS thanks, I understand why the extra comma is needed. Nothing to lose sleep over, just wanted to make sure that I am not missing any syntax.

Comment: Yes, you could also declare your method using an interface. It's a bit more verbose but, `interface MyFArA { f2: FArA }`.