# react typescript type based on other type

Tags: typescript

I have a component like this

```
type inputProps = {
  value: string | number | boolean
  onChange: (arg: string | number | boolean) => void
}

const Input = ({value, onChange}: inputProps) => {
  return <div />
}

const OtherComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(5)

  // onChange type not compatible
  return <Input  value={value} onChange={setValue} />
}

const AnotherComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('Hey')

  // onChange type not compatible
  return <Input  value={value} onChange={setValue} />
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAlgdmArsACgJwPZgM5QLxQDeAsAFBRQBuAhgDaIQBcU2wa8A5lAD5RyIBbAEYQ0PKEIwZaEanDIUMcAMIALORyZQAFNTQdmrdnC69+w0eMnTZcAJT4AfFQwwAJmQC+ZMgGMlrFAAkgjI+DqENPQQADRQSmoaEJ7M8EiomDgOeM4k5FBoEMCIaHBQADxuMJRQAPSOXj6k-nCBAPLAqqLKGAJgShBwwOHa2bkKUC2BANpRDHHYRQBqdAwAuuEASrK+wAB0iIsAysDUwBDaAKx2TRSFxaUVIekUcxB4kavJ8SrqJu+ERbAFbRTx1BqkbykPwBYYAQTgGE63V6-Tgg2GBFGTiIEymw1mXwWyy+GwI22ouwOx1O520AHIABIQED0m7Q-L3EplcrPMJUL4fN5ghJ-TQfIEghhg+peIA)

Is it possible to make the `arg` of the `onChange` function dependent on the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible using Generic Component

```
type InputProps<T> = {
  value: T;
  onChange: (arg: T) => void;
};

type AllowedTypes = string | boolean | number>;
    
const Input = <T extends AllowedTypes>({ value, onChange }: InputProps<T>) => {
  return <div />;
};
```

Comment: thanks! the `<T,>` looks a bit like magic rn, do we have any docs on what it does?

Comment: You can check this out for that syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics

Answer (score 0):

You can first define the `InputProps` as generic.

```
type InputProps<T extends string | number | boolean> = {
  value: T;
  onChange: (arg: T) => void;
};
```

Then you can use type union for different types.

```
const Input = ({
  value,
  onChange,
}: InputProps<string> | InputProps<number> | InputProps<boolean>) => {
  return <div />;
};

const OtherComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(5);

  return <Input value={value} onChange={setValue} />;
};

const AnotherComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('Hey');

  return <Input value={value} onChange={setValue} />;
};
```