# Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T | (() => T)'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want the `useFetch` hook to accept any kind of array to be used as the type of `data`:

**hooks/useFetch.ts:**

```
const useFetch = <T extends any[]>(dataUrl: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const result = await axios(dataUrl);
  
  setData(result.data);
}
```

Note: `result` is of type `AxiosResponse<any, any>`, and the successful `result.data` should be an object array. This is the [full code](https://gist.github.com/weiying-chen/756c976e7515612e44721c63de32e379) of the hook.

**App.tsx:**

```
interface City {
  rank: number;
  city: string;
  state: string;
  population: string;
}

const { data: cities, error } = useFetch<City[]>('/data.json');
```

I'm getting the following error on this line `const [data, setData] = useState<T>([]);`:

> Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T | (() => T)'.

How to remove this error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete code, specifically the part that calls `setData()`

Comment: @Phil I updated the answer. Is that enough?

Comment: Yep, cheers. [Minimally reproduced here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCAzgUwMpQIZTYgHgBUA+AChjBigC5EiBKOgbSIBpEz0o8AnOoogA+nMgAdeaAG4CGiALwl6DOYsRS4MACYBdRAG8AsAChEiSVBC8kzStQ5lVS-QF8dAbhMuTJiAhRQyOgAYmhQEAAWCoSCaAAeeGBaKIjYYACezDrkWrjYAKq8ADZ0AbyUAOZOBiZmfmABiMy5OBzcACJ5evJBmDh4xORZDJ7GLkA)

Comment: @Phil Thanks a lot. I'll add a live example in my future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had tried casting the `useState()` parameter to `T`, you would have seen an error like

> Conversion of type 'never[]' to type 'T' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. **If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first**.

The super simple version is to tell Typescript you know what you're doing and to shut up with the following...

```ts
const useFetch = <T extends any[]>(dataUrl: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T>([] as unknown as T);
```

---

Another approach you might want to try is creating an array-specific version of your hook, eg `useFetchArray`.

```ts
const useFetchArray = <T,>(dataUrl: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T[]>([]); //  note the T[] type here
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  // ...
}
```

With the consumer using

```ts
const { data: cities, error } = useFetchArray<City>('./data.json');
```

This avoids any ambiguity around generic array types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Question: why `<T,>` instead of just `<T>`?

Comment: @wyc my TS config tries to interpret it as JSX. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576880/283366)

Comment: One last question. I [implemented your code in my original  code](https://gist.github.com/weiying-chen/2f2cf71c6c99b40f857ff572cd415ad2). And I get this: `Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<T>'` in `setData(result.data);`. What could be the issue?

Comment: @wyc I think you've tried to use both parts of my answer. They are discrete options

Comment: I think I'm only using the first part of your answer [here](https://gist.github.com/weiying-chen/ba4e13628c1b30e31385c8230a4e9eec)? And I still get `Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<T>' in setData(result.data);`

Comment: Ah, it's the same problem as the initial data. Why not type the Axios response instead of using `any`... `const { data } = axios.get<T>(dataUrl);`?

Comment: Ah, that fixed the issue, thanks. But I still need `const [data, setData] = useState<T>([] as T);`. So I still need that generic. Otherwise, I get: `Argument of type 'T & any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type SetStateAction<never[]>`

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript doesn't know what type the empty array is, and so it is assigned to `never[]` by default. Casting the array to `T` via `useState<T>([] as T)` will also give you issues due to the same issue you're currently running into. Unless you explicitly need your generic to extend an array, you can simplify your `useFetch` declaration to:

```js
const useFetch = async <T>(dataUrl: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T[]>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const result = await axios(dataUrl);

  setData(result.data);
};
```